# Can a people DDOS a block Port?

Tags: networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding

The title says it all, I've search around the net but no avail. From what I understand, DDoS is a distributed denial of service attack, where multiple people sent a huge request at a same time which overload the webserver. (People can't access the website)

- For example I have port 80 **blocked** by my router firewall. Can anyone DDOS and overload the network?
- If I change to port 8080 for a webserver without people knowing, can they still shutdown a webserver if they are DDoS on a different port?
- This has been asked a lot but are there ways to mitigate the attack?

Comment: If a port has nothing running on it, then a connect on said port would be refused by the host. switching the port won't prevent a DDOS attack since people will know what port your running your website on since they can simply connect to it using a single connection.

Comment: Blocking a port means your computer or router will not answer any requests; this makes your server more hidden - but this will not prevent DOS attack at all - the volume of traffic is still coming in and using up your entire internet connection. Think of it as having 100 phones but 1,000 people are calling you. You could refuse to answer, but your lines are still congested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have blocked the only open port pointing to the system you shouldn't have an issue (since it doesn't accept traffic), although if you are going to block traffic you might as well turn off the port via your router.

Changing the port is largely pointless. Security through obscurity won't stop, for example, a generic HTTP DDoS request to the server, which is redirected by your router to whatever port/system specified. Anyone looking to do any sort of specific attack will likely run a port scanner and find the open ports.

There are various ways to mitigate DDoS attacks:

- Block any connection which makes a certain number of requests in a given time
- Use more complex systems like [DNS Sinkholes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_sinkhole)
- Web services which can assist with it such as [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/)

Comment: might his router be extra busy receiving a bombardment of packets on the albeit closed port? and perhaps his internet bandwidth?

Comment: I suppose that would depend on his router and what exactly he means by block. I have taken it to mean simply ignore traffic. Although it could be process each request and block it, which might very well flood the router.

Comment: Looking from an algorithmic perspective, it looks like there has to be some processing. e.g. process the incoming packet, what port is it on(what value does it have in the TCP DST PORT field), if that value is on a closed port, don't let it in. If it's part of an existing connection, let it in. If it's a new connection, on a port that is open, pass to the firewall and if it matches, port forward it.  i.e. even if it's a packet whose TCP DEST FIELD is a closed port, there is still processing - checking that field.